# IIS request timeout

Tags: iis, request, timeout

I am facing one issue.  Deployed my application on IIS 7.5 with windows 2009 R2. My observation is when I request page for the first time, IIS takes lots of time to render (which is understood as it is initialising the application). While this is going on of another user tries to use the website, they are getting time out. How do I improve it? Needs help you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 7.5 - on Windows Server 2008 R2, not 2009... - have a look at the [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization]). Or better, upgrade to IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (if possible), where it's [built in](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization).